# Can I get a full command line as a single string instead of process.argv in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

[Node.js Process docs](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv):

> The `process.argv` property returns an array containing the command-line arguments passed when the Node.js process was launched.

This is probably as far as it gets, but I just want to double-check. Because `process.argv` makes things more complicated for what I have in mind. Gluing it back will make a bad service either.

Ideally, I would love to see links to discussions on why it is done this way only, or an example how to get a raw command line without duct tape.

Comment: you can even inserting your command line between double quotes like this " your argument".
how about you use a package called as yargs. its increases the functionality of command line parsing.

Comment: Quotes is one of the reasons why it can't be glued back in the same way it was run. And I know about yargs. It has nothing to do with my problem.